# httpd don't find image with special characters

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have a wordpress site and when I upload image with french name like this (sécurité) my server don't find the image and the brower return my a 404 erreur. But the image is on the server .

I try a lot of thing like but nothing work

1: i add this on my `httpd.conf`

```
AddDefaultCharset on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

2:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .png
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8
```

3:

i tyr to change the defaut languege of the server on the i18n file for this:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
SUPPORTED="en_US.utf8:en_US:en:fr_FR.utf8:fr_FR:fr :es_ES.utf8:es_ES:es:de_DE.utf8:de_DE:de:sv_SE.utf 8:sv_SE:sv:zh_CN.utf8:
zh_CN:zh:zh_TW.utf8:zh_TW:zh:ja_JP.utf8:ja_JP:ja:k o_KR.utf8:ko_KR:ko"
```

4: all on this page

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions

on my .htacces i have this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How did you upload the image to the server? What is the content of `/etc/fstab` for the file system where you are storing HTTP daemon files?

Comment: the fstab look at this

LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0

and the conf path is /etc/httpd/conf

Comment: Please add the information to the question in a code block. It is hard to read from a comment. Also, you didn't answer the first question.